# how to pass uint[] c# to c++ dll?

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I am developing a C# program that communicates with a C++ DLL.

The structure type in the provided C++ DLL is as follows:

```cpp
struct ST_TEST
{
    unsigned long* anIDs;
    unsigned long anIDCount;
};
```

The C# structure I created to match the above structure is as follows:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ST_TEST
{
    public IntPtr anIDs;
    public uint anIDCount;
}
```

After that, what I wanted to do was set the object of the C# structure to pass that structure from C# to C++, like this:

```cs
uint[] IDs = { 12824874, 7865845, 45875792 };

ST_TEST stTest = new ST_TEST();
stTest.anIDCount = (uint)IDs.Length;

IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(IDs.Length);
try{
          Marshal.Copy(IDs, 0, buffer, IDs.Length);
          stTest.anIDs = buffer;
          //... call c++ dll
}
finally
{
          Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
}
```

When executed as above, the following error occurs in `Marshal.Copy()`:

> Can't convert from uint[] to int[]

How do I pass `uint[]` as an `unsigned long*` to a C++ DLL?

Comment: For the record, you're working on too low a level and without the proper tools, `Span<>` and `stackalloc`. You should pick a side, proper low-level code or just use a managed array (like you already allocated, your `IDs`) and properly annotate your structure to work as-is with the marshaller.

Comment: Please explain it a little more easily. Do you mean that it is better to create a clr project in the middle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `uint` because the Marshal class doesn't have an overload for that type, since it is
not CLS compliant.

However, since you're copying the bytes in the array, `int` will work, since it is the correct size,
and the C++ code will still consider the array elements to be `uint` when it receives them.

Also, note that when using `Marshal.AllocHGlobal()`, you must specify the number of *bytes*, not the
number of array elements.

Be sure not to call `Marshal.FreeHGlobal()` until after the C++ function has returned AND is no longer
using the array pointer.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ST_TEST
{
  public IntPtr anIDs;
  public int anIDCount;
 }
        
public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    try
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
      int[] IDs = { 12824874, 7865845, 45875792 };
      ST_TEST stTest = new ST_TEST();
      stTest.anIDCount = IDs.Length;
      IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(IDs.Length * sizeof(int));
      Marshal.Copy(IDs, 0, buffer, IDs.Length);
      stTest.anIDs = buffer;
      // ... call native function
      // ...
    }
    finally
    {
      Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` should be in a `finally` block

Comment: In the end, uint is not possible and I have to change it to int .. It would be impossible to put uint.maxvalue and so on... It is difficult to use the provided c++ dll. 
Thank you for your kind example. also checked the part of putting free in the finally statement.
Thank you all so much.